# What would be a good method for detecting symbols in an image and finding those elsewhere?

Tags: feature-selection, computer-vision, library

I'm trying to build a system that can detect symbols from a legend image, then find and count those symbols in a diagram

For example the legend would have symbols like this, with a label next to them to describe what they are.

[image: Photo of a legend showing symbols next to their label]

Then in a diagram like this, I want the system to count and determine the location of each symbol mentioned.

[image: Diagram of symbols in use]

Its worth noting that this won't be pixel perfect like it is in this example.  It may be an image scan and will need some fault tolerance.

Is there a library that would be capable of doing this?  If someone could point me in the right direction I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: You can use template matching available in OpenCV. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853628/how-do-i-find-an-image-contained-within-an-image) thread.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal that helps with the second half, but I'm still having trouble finding a solution for the first half.  I need a method for detecting symbols from a symbol legend, and turning those symbols into pictures that I pass into the template matcher.

Comment: We can first detect text and its position. Next, we draw a fixed size rectangle from the detected text positions so that the image (symbol) can be enclosed in it.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I’m a maintenance mechanic who has been searching for an app or software that can identify electrical and hydraulic diagram symbols.